# how to construct JSON before submitting form using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I have the following [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fmuW6/2/) on jsFiddle. I would like to submit this form using javascript and send a JSON object back to my controller.

As you can see multiple rows can be added to the table and submitted. In my JSON data I would like to keep track of which checkboxes got clicked for which rows. So for example, based on the below screen shot:

[image]

I would like the JSON object to look like this:

```
{light:[{red:on}, {yellow:off},{green:on}], dark:[{red:off}, {yellow:off},{green:on}]}...
```

Comment: If you are to take my advice use malsup's [form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started)

Comment: I took a quick look at it. but it was not putting results in the format i wanted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code I came up with looks like this:

```
var jsonObject = {};
$('.input-row').each(function(index, row) {
    var innerObject = {};
    $(':checkbox', row).each(function(index, checkbox) {
        innerObject[checkbox.name] = checkbox.checked ? 'on' : 'off';
    });
    var key = $('input[type="text"]', row).val();
    jsonObject[key] = innerObject;
});
console.log(jsonObject);
// use jsonObject somehow
```

We're creating an empty object that will be our overall JSON object (called `jsonObject`).

Then we're iterating over each of the rows of inputs (I've added an `input-row` class to these so they can be selected easily).

For each row, we create another empty object (called `innerObject`), then iterate over its checkboxes. For each checkbox, we add a property to `innerObject`: the key is the `name` attribute/property of the checkbox, the value is `on` or `off` depending on the `checked` state. Finally, we get the value of the `text` input on that row to use as the key in `jsonObject`, and add the property to it.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fmuW6/3/) of the above code.

Comment: Thanks. jsFiddle seems to be down at the moment. I'll try it soon as its up. The code looks fine though

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to serialize a form as JSON is to use `jQuery's serializeArray()`

```
JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray());
```

Comment: That won't give him anywhere near the object structure he desires, though. It may be easier to use that, and modify the server-side code, or it may be easier to write a jQuery function to provide JSON in the format he wants.

Comment: hmm I'm getting this type of json: `[{"name":"red","value":"on"},{"name":"green","value":"on"},{"name":"green","value":"on"}]` here is the updated link for fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fmuW6/4/

Answer (score 0):

You should build your own JSON string and then use `jQuery.parseJSON()` to do this loop all your tr elements in the table and collect the information you need.

The below code is a start for you according the html in fiddler.

```
var strJSON = '';

$("#blacklistgrid tr").each(function (i) { 
    if (i != 0) 
    { 
        var currentRow = $(this)
        strJSON += "{ " + currentRow.find("input[name='shade']").val() +"[{red: currentRow.find("input[name='red']").is(":checked")} ]   }";
    } 
});

var theJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(strJSON);
```

please check the correct format for JSON string and I could not check the code if it working but you can get the logic here.

Comment: Anthony's solution is the better and the correct one. Why I thought parsing from string I don't know.